# Adding fade in, fade out to dim light - javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am looking for an answer to the fading in and\or out, of the feature "Dim Lights". Here below is some coding;

```
<!--HEAD-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/embeddedcontent.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dimmed = 0;
  function toggleLights()
  {
    var dimmer = document.getElementById("dimmer");
    if(dimmed == 0) dimmed = 1;
    else dimmed = 0;

    if(dimmed == 1)
    {
        dimmer.style.opacity = 1.0;
        dimmer.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if(dimmed == 0)
    {
        dimmer.style.opacity = 0.0;
        dimmer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
  </script>
 <style type="text/css">
  .aboveDimmer
  {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 301;
  }
  #dimmer
  {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    z-index: 300;
    visibility:hidden;
    background-color:#000000;
  }
  </style>

<!--BODY-->

    <div id="dimmer" onclick="toggleLights()"></div>
    Click to<a href="javascript:toggleLights();"><b> Dim the Lights</b></a>
```

There is more to it but if you visit [http://www.ittookamiracle.ca/'11daniel.htm](http://www.ittookamiracle.ca/%2711daniel.htm) as an example of how it works and any other detail of coding needed to answer my question.

Thank you for taking your time to look in to this.

Cheers,

Jason.

Comment: Please state clearly in your question what you're asking for. What doesn't work?

Comment: The code all works. I am wanting to add "fadein" when the you click on the "Dim the Lights" link. what code would I use?

Comment: Oh also I talked with a friend that has a Mac Laptop and he says it doesnt work from him. How do I fix it so that Mac users can also use the "Dim the Lights" Option?

Comment: You ought to try [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It'll take care of your cross-browser and transition needs.

Comment: It does fade fast into the dim light, but I would like to know if there is a code that is able to make adjustments on how fast or slow you can fade in and out. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/quick-tip-dim-the-lights-using-flash-and-jquery/) on how to make a dim the light button using flash and jquery.

This is the [demo page](http://activetuts.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/187_QTlightSwitch/Preview/index.html) demoing the script